Must constants denote exactly one thing?
Consider the algebraic equation
C2 - 1 = 0
C is a constant.
When we solve this equation we report it's solution as C = 1 or C = -1.  But that can't be an exclusive or.  Thus, we can say C = 1 and C = -1.  Therefore, this is an example of a situation where a constant denotes two things.
So my question is, must constants always denote exactly one thing, or is that an assumption that isn't necessarily true.

You could think of C as representing the solution set, each element of which is a constant which refers to exactly one object

@Joseph_Kopp, that wouldn't be right.  Because both sides represent numbers, the LHS represents a number.  Then by the converse of the closure axiom of addition, C^2 denotes a number.  Then by the converse of the closure axiom of multiplication, C denotes a number.  Therefore, C cannot denote a set, so it cannot represent the solution set as you suggest.  C denotes two numbers, not one set with two elements.

It's an exclusive or.

@leepappas Probably the better way to do it would then be to view it as a problem with the "overuse" of C. C=1 and C=-1 can't be simultaneously true. Rather, these should be indexed as C1 and C2 and be considered elements of the solution set or "domain" of C, and therefore C may be considered a variable which "varies" between C1 and C2.

@Joseph_Kopp, why can't they be simultaneously true?

@leepappas Principle of explosion? I get that they're both valid solutions to the equation, but as statements on their own they give a contradiction. I suppose by Godel's incompleteness that it's technically not impossible, but that'd be a pretty impractical interpretation when it's just as fine to view the statements as not actually contradictory via a change in notation.

@Joseph_Kopp, you are using transitivity of equality, but transitivity of equality doesn't apply here.  IF (if x=y & y=z then x=z) then x,y,z are specific constants, meaning they denote exactly one thing each.  But here C denotes two things so transitivity of equality doesn't apply.  So there is no contradiction, hence ex falso sequitur quodlibet doesn't apply.

@leepappas x,y,z are variables which may be instantiated with specific constants via substitution. If this were not the case, then somehow constants and variables would exist as mutually exclusive objects which is impractical. The way I see it is that when a variable is used, it is used so that the statement containing it represents the class of all propositions that may be generated via instantiating the variable with different constants from its domain. This is kind of what I meant when I said to view C as the solution set (although I wasn't expressing myself clearly when saying that).

@Joseph_Kopp,   constants and variables are mutually exclusive objects, why do you say that's impractical?  When a variable is used, the PROPOSITIONAL FUNCTION containing it does not represent anything.  Only constants represent things, and a propositional function isn't a constant.  So it can't represent a set, so it can't represent the set of all propositions that may be produced via instantiating the variable with different constants.

C is not a constant in your example; it is a variable. if it were a constant, the  notion of a solution would make no sense.

@DavidGudeman, C denotes two numbers, each number that C denotes is a solution.  That makes sense to me.

How is C a constant? How are you defining a constant?

We don't report the solution as C = 1 or C = -1, that is sloppy notation. The solution is either the elements of the set {-1,1} or we say that C_1 = 1 is a solution and C_2 = -1 is a solution.

By way of example, see Constant: in computer programming, a constant is a value that is not altered by the program during normal execution. This is contrasted with a variable, which is an identifier with a value that can be changed during normal execution. To simplify, constants' values remains, while the values of variables varies, hence both their names.

You do not give any reason to believe that your C is a "constant". How do you define that word, anyhow? Or are you confusing the concept of a constant with the concept of a symbol?

@DanielAsimov, I treat 'symbol' as undefined, and C is a constant iff there exists an x, such that x=C.  This has the advantage of permitting a mind to use free logic, in which a symbol might not denote anything.  For example, Jehovah is a symbol that does not denote, but the sentence "Jehovah does not exist" is not meaningless in free logic.
